ThisWorkbook.Path is blank on template
I'm helping a sporting organisation that is comprised mostly of elderly peeps by configuring a user form in Excel that sets up a competition format based on a number of event parameters.
What happens now is, based on the comp, the tournament manager has to select a particular base workbook then copy dozens of named ranges from other workbook templates which is quite tedious and prone to error making resulting in non-functioning formulas.
So, I've written a user form for the base workbook template with various controls that the tournament manager selects which will automate the whole event workbook being created and ready to enter data. Now, I wrote about 1500 lines of code (I'm not a programmer), that pulls the named ranges from various files that are in the same directory as the template and works fine under testing except, I was testing the template workbook itself as I was writing/editing it's code.
If I double click the workbook template file as a normal person would do (wherever they have saved all the files on their PC), the user form fails as the functions I wrote uses the workbook path relative to the template I was editing (ThisWorkbook.Path). The nature of double clicking a template causes the path to be null ("") because you are creating a 'copy', not editing the template file until it is saved. Once the comp workbook is created, it has no need for access to the templates so it can be saved anywhere to function properly and manage the actual tournament.
Forcing the user to save the file before running the form doesn't necessarily work either as default directories vary between on people's PCs and the user may save the workbook in a particular directory or online, (my laptop and desktop alone use different default directory paths) where the template files aren't in the same directory so the workbook path doesn't relate.
So, my question is, how do I obtain the actual path of the workbook template file when double clicking it, so I can run the form on Workbook_Open() with the correct relative path until the user form executes and closes, which then requests the file to be immediately saved?

Maybe instead of using a template, mark the "base" workbook as read-only, so the user has to save a copy once the content has been set up by your code.

Sorry, I'm confused, if you double click any template it opens as a copy, with a temporary file name workbook1.xltm?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What I need is in the last paragraph... as stated?

I'm saying just use a regular non-template xlsm instead of xltm, and mark the file as read-only, so the user can't save it directly but needs to choose where to save it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774890/finding-an-excel-spreadsheets-template-path

Thanks @FunThomas but I've already looked at that and it means hardcoding an path and getting everyone that uses the templates files to specifically put them in a particular folder to get it to work.
I'll try Tim Williams suggestion...
